# Curve Text In Asp.Net Page

Tags: c#, html, css

I want to take the text Good Job and curve it around a circle so the Top Right-Left reads Good and the bottom Left-Right Job.  How can this be achieved using html/css?

Let me add with no extra plugin dependencies required.

Comment: You could've found your answer quicker by searching - https://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/

Comment: @Dayan - that requires Lettering.js  I would like to achieve this w/o any additional tools